# Envelope Distort: Stratight lines, not curvy

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I want to replicate the style of this logo: 
[image]

I'm using AI and this is what I have tried so far:

1) Create text,
2) Create polygon shape 
3) Envelope Distort

This is the result: [image]

As you can see the text is curved. Is there a way to re-create the "rectangular" effect of the original logo?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to get it as accurate as you will require it for a logo using envelopes.

I would try one of the following methods to create a logo in this style.

1. Use the perspective grid (although this could be fiddly)
2. Create the text, and then cut the logo down the centre using the
   divide tool, and then use the transform tool on one side of the logo
   until you are happy with the perspective, then reverse the effect on
   the other side and match them up.

Comment: You beat me to it! #2 is how I'd do it. Here's what I was able to do with the transform tool: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iSAcQ.png